# Configure Runtime Versions in CDKPipeline SynthAction

Tags: aws-cdk

we are deploying Go Lambdas via the CDKPipeline construct and need to compile the Go code as part of our synth step.

Now we wanted to update to go 1.15, which is only possible if we use the new Codebuild Standard 5.0. The Codebuild Image itself is configurable via the SimpleSynthOptions field `environment`. But there seems to be no straight forward way to pass runtime-versions. This is a field introduced, which is defined under the `install:` key. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-runtime-versions.html), but the install step is completely non configurable in the `SimpleSynthAction` class.

The only way I currently see is to override the `bind` function in the `SimpleSynthAction` class. There also seems to be no way to introduce a separate Codebuild step before the Synth step from what I've seen?

Did I overlook any options or is this really the only way? And if so, would this be worth a feature request to make runtime-versions configurable as part of the synthAction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the latest CdkPipeline API you can customize the build spec: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/pipelines-readme.html#customizing-codebuild-projects

For example, using the `synthCodeBuildDefaults` to specify nodejs 14:

```ts
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
    synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
        input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, "mainline"),
        commands: [
            "npm ci",
            "npm run build",
            "cd packages/infrastructure",
            "npx cdk synth",
        ],
        primaryOutputDirectory: "packages/infrastructure/cdk.out",
    }),
    synthCodeBuildDefaults: {
        partialBuildSpec: BuildSpec.fromObject({
            phases: {
                install: {
                    "runtime-versions": {
                        nodejs: "14"
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading some [more docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) my problem solved itself, because if no runtime-versions are given the default is taken. So when I updated to standard 5.0, go 1.15 was used by default.

However for the general purpose of defining additional runtime-versions I'll create a feature request as this seems to be impossible to define currently.